# XPath Query to get the <a> tag and <b> tag

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I tried to get the values from  and  tag using Xpath query whole day and i couldn't. Can somebody help me with xpath query i need to use in order to get them. Please see the below html code.

```
<html class="chrome webkit">
#shadow-root
<head>...</head>
<body id="jira" class="aui-layout aui-theme-default page-type-dashboard" data-version="6.1.2" data-aui-version="5.1.6">
<div id="page">
<header id="header" role="banner">...</header>
<div id="announcement-banner" class="alertHeader">
  <b> Production </b>
  <marquee scrollamoun="3" behaviour="alternate" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout ="this.start()">..</marquee>
<#shadow-root
<font-color="red"> Note:Please check out 1.</font>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/a/query.com/document/" target="_blank">
 <b>
  <font color ="red"> GSD Service </font>
 </b>
</a>
</marquee>
</div>
<section id="content" role="main">...</section>
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">...</footer>
</div>
<div class="shim hidden"></div>
<div class="shim hidden"></div>
<div class="shim hidden"></div>
<div class="shim hidden"></div>
<div class="shim hidden"></div>
<div class="shim hidden"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Similarly i have another three a tags after this tag , so i wanted to get all the a tags as well as b tags separately to show it in my application.Please help me with the XPath Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML is [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), the following XPath will select all `a` elements:

```
//a
```

Just the first `a`:

```
(//a)[1]
```

Just the first `a` within the `div` whose `@id` is `page`:

```
(//div[@id='page']//a)[1]
```

You can equally easily apply these concepts to selecting `b`.

### Update

The following XPath will select all `a` elements you indicated in the comments that you need:

```
//div[@id='page']//div[@id='announcement-banner']//a[@target='_blank']
```

**Notes:**

- While your comment asked for `target="_blank"`, the `a` in your
  posted HTML has `target="_blank"`, so you may need to adjust.
- If you want immediate containment rather than containment at any depth, use `/` rather than `//`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer , but i already tried - @"//div[@id='page']"; to get the page but as you mentioned. I want to go inside the <div> announcement banner tag and go inside the marquee tag and then finally get the <a> and <b> tags , i tried with yours - "//div[@id='page']//a[1]" . Can you let me know how to get the div tags inside another div tag with my case and then then the a tags and b tags.

Comment: Sorry , i checked again now its working perfectly , but it is showing all the a tags, but i only need 5 tags out of them , how to select particular ones that i need and if i get that bingo i have the exact answer.

Comment: What distinguishes the 5 `a` elements that you do want from those that you do not want?

Comment: They have this tag :  target="_blank" and one more problem is that the answer you gave me is pulling all the <a> tags from div[@id='page'] but all the <a> tags that i need are in "announcement banner" div tag. can you please let me know how to access the announcement banner div tag which is inside the  id="page" <div> tag.

Comment: hi ,Thank you very much i tried the updates xpath you gave me but the problem is that when i use even the -@"//div[@id='page']//div[@id='announcement-banner']";

Comment: It is giving me 0 objects , i dont know why it is doing that but the - @"//div[@id='page']"; is working fine and giving me the objects.can you please look into it.

Comment: We would have to see the entire relevant section of HTML to assess why `//div[@id='page']//div[@id='announcement-banner']//a[@target='_blank']` is not selecting the `a` elements you want.

Comment: I need atleast 10 points to post an image as that would be easy , Can you please let me know if you could give your email so that i may send you an image or any other form of communication is better .

Comment: Post the relevant HTML as text, not as an image.  Never post code or markup as an image.

Comment: That HTML is not well-formed:  `<#shadow-root` is a problem; `<font-color="red">` is another.  Bowing out here.  Too much back-and-forth is not a good fit for Stack Overflow questions.   I hope I've helped you understand (a) how to write XPaths and (b) HTML has to be well-formed to be a good target for XPath.  Good luck.